# How to display monetary value in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, types, currency

My database query is below, but I still can't display a monetary value properly. Please help me.

```
SELECT  SUM (orders.quantity * products.price) as total,
to_char((orders.quantity * products.price), '$99,999,999.99') AS money
    FROM
       orders
       inner join products on products.id = orders.products_id
       inner join customers on customers.id = orders.customers_id
    WHERE order_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
      AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 days';
```

My problem is that I get this error:

```
ERROR: column "orders.quantity" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really say what your problem was, but if you use the `FM` format modifier as in

```
SELECT to_char(12345.67, '$99,999,999.99FM');

  to_char   
------------
 $12,345.67
(1 row)
```

the result might be more to your liking.

To make the query work without an error, add a `GROUP BY` clause at the end like

```
... GROUP BY money
```

Comment: I keep getting an error like this:

ERROR:  column "orders.quantity" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: to_char(orders.quantity * products.price, '$99,999,999.99') ...

Comment: Oh, I see. That was simple.

Comment: I get 31295 when I did not put the money format. The GROUP BY clause worked, but i get different value.

Comment: No, the formatting has nothing to do with that. You probably get duplicates because you join three tables. But that's a different question, right?